# Django Rest Framework JSON API - Update M2M relationship not persisting

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, json-api

I'm trying to update a resource in a `PATCH`.

The resource is updated fine, but the resources in the M2M table don't change.

**Models**

```
class StatementOfAdvice(Model):
    id = HashidUnsignedAutoField(primary_key=True, salt="StatementOfAdvice", min_length=15)
    loan_purposes = ManyToManyField(
        to=StaticLoanPurpose, through=StatementOfAdviceLoanPurpose, related_name="loan_purposes"
    )

class StaticLoanPurpose(Model):
    id = CharField(db_column="loan_purpose_id", primary_key=True, max_length=150)
    value = CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)

class StatementOfAdviceLoanPurpose(Model):
    id = HashidUnsignedAutoField(primary_key=True, salt="StatementOfAdviceLoanPurpose", min_length=15)

    statement_of_advice = ForeignKey(to="StatementOfAdvice", on_delete=DO_NOTHING)
    loan_purpose = ForeignKey(to="StaticLoanPurpose", on_delete=DO_NOTHING)
```

**Serializers**

```
class StatementOfAdviceSerializer(Serializer):
    included_serializers = {"client_account": ClientAccountSerializer, "loan_purpose": StaticLoanPurposeSerializer}
    loan_purposes = ResourceRelatedField(many=True, read_only=False, queryset=StaticLoanPurpose)

    class Meta:
        model = StatementOfAdvice
        fields = "_all_"

class StaticLoanPurposeSerializer(Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = StaticLoanPurpose
        fields = "_all_"
```

**My `PATCH` request:** `http://localhost:8000/statements_of_advice/zELX1KdyZjgQGkp/`

**Payload:**

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "StatementOfAdvice",
        "attributes": {},
        "relationships": {
            "loan_purposes": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "type": "StaticLoanPurpose",
                        "id": "construct_io"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "StaticLoanPurpose",
                        "id": "other_purpose"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "StaticLoanPurpose",
                        "id": "purchase_io"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "id": "zELX1KdyZjgQGkp"
    }
}
```

The result I expect from this **`PATCH`** request is 3 records in the linking table `StatementOfAdviceLoanPurpose`. But I get none.

If anyone could help me here I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You need to implement `create()` and `update()` as mentioned here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

Comment: @DanielM thanks for pointing me out to the right direction! I really appreciate it. I thought that deleting and adding relationships to a linking table would be handled automatically by the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Then. The solution I found was actually using `rest_framework_json_api.views.AutoPrefetchMixin` in my `StatementOfAdviceViewSet`.

```
class StatementOfAdviceViewSet(BaseViewSet, AutoPrefetchMixin):
    queryset = StatementOfAdvice.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StatementOfAdviceSerializer
    filterset_class = StatementOfAdviceFilterSet
```

**Reference link:**
https://django-rest-framework-json-api.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apidoc/rest_framework_json_api.views.html?highlight=manytomany#rest_framework_json_api.views.AutoPrefetchMixin.get_queryset

But this only fixes part of the problem. Now I can insert records in the linking table using the same payload as in the question.
But I cannot remove them. I tried changing the request method to `PUT` assuming that since `PUT` is supposed to replace all values of the resource the framework would handle it to me. But it doesn't.

So besides adding the `AutoPrefetchMixin` in the viewset. I also had override the `update()` function in the `StatementOfAdviceSerializer` to achieve the desired behaviour.

The advantage of using `AutoPrefetchMixin` is that you don't have to override the `create()` method.